# Is this cosine function surjective?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I have a function with:

Domain:$\left[-\frac\pi2, \frac\pi2\right]$

Range: $[-1, 1]$

$f(x)= \cos{ x^2 }$

I thought about it in this way:

I want to know, without graphing, that the function can output the full codomain, from $-1$ to $1$.

I tried to find a value of the domain when squared $=180$ degrees, that's when cosine is $-1$. An angle of $13.42$ degrees satisfies this requirement.

I know that cosine is $1$ when the angle $= 0. 0$ is in the domain.

However, the problem asks for radians and that's where I get stuck.

Again, I tried to find a value that when squared, produces $\pi$ ($=180$ degrees), but such a value does not exist within the functions domain.

Why does it work with degrees, but not radians?

Comment: The function does _not_ output the whole codomain. The range is not $[-1,1]$ with that domain.

Comment: Is there any logical explanation as to why it works with degrees but not radians. Thank you.

Comment: Is that $(\cos x)^2$ or $\cos(x^2)$?

Comment: When is $\cos(x)$ is the same as $\cos(x^2)$? If it's in degrees, then they're the same when $x=1^\circ$. If it's in radians, then they're the same when $x=1^{\text{rad}}$. Clearly, these are very different angles. Does this help explain why it matters if it's in degrees or radians?

Comment: @Akiva, thank you. It's clear.